# ngrx store does not update UI after dispatched action from firebase promise

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript, ngrx-store

I am trying to develop a basic NativeScript app using Angular 4. I am also using ngrx store and firebase as a realtime database.

When I use a sample array and update the store and not integrate with firebase the program works fine. UI gets updated too.

```
let value = [
    {
        "description": "Groups discussing about Technology",
        "category": "Tech"
    },
    {
        "description": "Groups for all kinds of sports ",
        "category": "Sports"
    }
];

this.store.dispatch({ type: GroupCategoryListActions.ADD_ITEMS, payload: value });
this.store.dispatch({ type: GroupCategoryListActions.LOAD_SUCCESS });
```

However when I integrate with firebase and try to retrieve the same data using a firebase query, although the query returns the same array as in the above code sample but the UI doesn't get updated. Below is the code to fetch from firebase.

```
firebase.init()
    .then((result) => {
        firebase.query(
            (result) => {
                if(!result)
                    this.store.dispatch({ type: GroupCategoryListActions.LOAD_ERROR });

                this.store.dispatch({ type: GroupCategoryListActions.ADD_ITEMS, payload: result.value });
                this.store.dispatch({ type: GroupCategoryListActions.LOAD_SUCCESS });
            },
            '/groupCategory',
            {
                orderBy: {
                    type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.KEY,
                    value: 'category'
                }
            });
    },
        (error) => console.log("firebase.init error: " + error)
    );
```

Here is the url to my [firebase database](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/herd-f8b8c/database/data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's entirely normal behavior for Angular; the query promise is not part of the Angular lifecycle. That's not specific to the Firebase plugin by the way.

You can use NgZone to make the result attach to the Angular lifecycle so your view will update. Inject `zone: NgZone` in your `@Component` `constructor` and wrap the stuff after `(result) => {` in `this.zone.run(() => { /* your result-handling code here */})`.

Comment: That worked but it got triggered twice. Do I need to enableProdMode or is there any other work around? Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a difference in those `result` objects? And doesn't it get triggered twice as well when not using `NgZone`?

Comment: I am dumber than you can think of. It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer but if you have some time would you care to explain why we need to wrap it in zone.run? I thought since there is a direct subscription to the items in store we need not explicitly run it in angular's context. I may have messed up with my logic but your reply on this would help me to understand it clearly.

Comment: I can't explain it in a better way, but I'm sure Googling something like "when to use NgZone" will enlighten you ;)

Comment: My doubt was specific to observables. Anyways, will have a look. Thanks :)

Comment: @EddyVerbruggen I am on angular 9 and I have my redirect placed inside the zone as suggested. I have to click twice on my login button to make the navigation happen. Authentication happens in the first call, but redirection does not happen. In the second call only, redirection happens.

Comment: Okay, I had some other issue there. After adding a / at the start of the url, it started working. I still cannot figure out how the redirection happened in the second attempt earlier tho