# Firebase routing after authentication

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-material, angular-router

I have the following problem : when I use the promise returned by firebase authentication to navigate to my register page, I obtain two pages displayed at the same time instead of only my register page:

- The login page with my social buttons
- my register page (without any css applied) with the profile details wanted for the application

Version of my modules:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 8.6.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 5.1.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.6.0
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-beta.10-4905443
@angular/material: 5.0.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.35
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.41
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.10
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.10
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack-bundle-analyzer: 2.9.1
webpack: 3.10.0
```

And the code in login.component.ts :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,  private router: Router) {}

  ...

  loginWith(mode: string) {
    return this.authService.loginWith(mode).then((data) => {
      if(data.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
         this.router.navigate(['register', {mode: mode}]).catch(error => {
           console.log("Navigate ERROR", error);
         });
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
    });
 }
```

And the code of auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { login, logout } from './auth.reducer';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private store: Store<any>) {}
  public redirectUrl: string;


  /**
   * Logs in the user
   * @returns {firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState>}
   */
  loginWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((data) => {
      this.store.dispatch(login(data));
      return data;
    });
  }

  loginWith(mode : string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new this.afAuth.auth[mode + 'AuthProvider']()).then((data) => {
      this.store.dispatch(login(data));
      return data;
    });
  }
```

**What I've tried :**

*Suppression of all my animations*

The result was the same : a mix between m

*Direct routing*

```
loginWith(mode: string) {
  this.router.navigate(['register', {mode: mode}]);
}
```

The result was OK, I've obtained my register page

*Usage of Ngrx*

Not finalized, just used to check the behaviour of the component.

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { selectorAuth } from '../auth.reducer';
...
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
...
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,  private router: Router, private store: Store<any>) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  loginWith(mode: string) {
    this.store
      .select(selectorAuth)
      .subscribe(auth => {
        if(auth.isAuthenticated) {
          if(auth.payload.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
            this.router.navigate(['register', {mode: mode}]).catch(error => {
               console.log("Navigate ERROR", error);
            });
          }
        }
      });

    return this.authService.loginWith(mode);
  }
...
}
```

The result was KO : always the mix between the two pages

I think I've missed something but I don't know where and what, so if someone can help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in this post :
[ngrx store does not update UI after dispatched action from firebase promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651990/ngrx-store-does-not-update-ui-after-dispatched-action-from-firebase-promise)

The call of the redirect was'nt in the angular scope so it's necessary to use NgZone to make the redirect functionnal.

So my code is now :

```
  loginWith(mode: string) {
    return this.authService.loginWith(mode).then((data) => {
      if(data.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['register', {mode: mode}]);
          });
        });
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
    });
  }
```